# Receiving Your Pipfile requires python_version 3.7, but you are using unknown, when running pytest even though I have Python 3.7.0 installed

Tags: python, pytest

When I run `pipenv run pytest`  on my Windows machine, I get the following message:

> Warning: Your Pipfile requires python_version **3.7**, but you are using **unknown**
> (C:\Users\d.\v\S\python.exe).

> $ pipenv --rm and rebuilding the
> virtual environment may resolve the issue.
> $ pipenv check will surely fail

I have tried running `pipenv --rm`, `pipenv install` & re-running the tests but I get the same error message.

Under Programs and Features, I have Python 3.7.0 (64-bit) & Python Launcher so I'm not sure where it is getting the ***unkown*** version from.

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, the following fixed my issue.

1. Updating pip using the 'c:\users...\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command
2. adding PYTHONPATH (pointing to the directory with the pipfil) to enviroment variables
3. removing the current virtualenv (pipenv --rm)
4. and reinstalling (pipenv install)